# Find two non-constant functions, $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, such that $(f(t))^{2} + (g(t))^{2} = k^{2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need to find two functions, $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, such that $(f(t))^{2} + (g(t))^{2} = k^{2}$, where $k$ is a constant, given $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are NOT constant functions.

I can see that when $f(t)$ increases with $t$, $g(t)%$ should decrease with $t$, so that the sum of their squares remains constant. But for some reason, I cannot find two example functions in $t$ for this case.

Comment: $k\sin t, k\cos t$？

Comment: @ling Thanks! I didn't think of trigonometric functions eventhough I was trying to connect it to circular motion. Serious brain fade!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be $f(t) = k\cdot\cos t$ and $g(t) = k\cdot\sin t$, since $$f(t)^2+g(t)^2 = k^2\cdot\underbrace{(\cos^2t + \sin^2t)}_{=1} = k^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

A pair of functions satisfying this functional equation are $k \cdot \sin(t)$ and $k \cdot \cos(t)$.

Comment: Only if $k=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any non-constant function $f$ such that $f(t)<k$. Then, define $g(t)=\sqrt{k^2-f^2(t)}$.

For example, you could take $f(t)=\frac{k}{1+t^2}$ and $$g(t)=\sqrt{\frac{k^2+k^2t^2 - k}{1+t^2}}$$

---

Or, you could also take the obvious $k\sin t, k\cos t$, of course. But I wanted to show with my example that there are infinitely many such function pairs.